# Mobile Backend Starter

Tags: java, android

I installed [Mobile Backend Starter](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/). After successful installation, I got problem after running the android client:

```
com.google.cloud.backend
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
```

It's error in array, but I can't find it. Whats wrong with sample project of Mobile Backend Starter?

Comment: Can you post complete log cat ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the repository source sample code. It is probably a bug in their library.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-android-client/search?q=charAt&ref=cmdform

DDMS/Monitor should give you the class and stack trace.

What if you try a previous version?